# Selecting fields from a table along with an aggregate of data in another table it has a one-to-many relationship with

Tags: mysql, inner-join

**Problem Background**

This type of query seems to be my 'white whale' - I just can't wrap my head around how to do it. I have a solution below but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do things - e.g. is my solution very inefficient and likely to  slow my query down a lot?

If I have a table, for example - `_UserInfo` - and I have a related table, for example - `_UserOrders`, how can I `SELECT` some fields from `_UserInfo` along with aggregates from `_UserOrders`?

---

**Details / Attempts at a Solution**

_UserInfo

```
UserID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY_KEY
FirstName VARCHAR(50)
LastName VARCHAR(50)
```

_UserOrders

```
UserID INT UNSIGNED 
OrderID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY 
Cost DECIMAL(8,2)
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES _UserInfo(UserID)
```

---

I can very easily `SELECT` each user's `FirstName` and `LastName` -

```
SELECT 
    _UserInfo.FirstName AS `FirstName`,
    _UserInfo.LastName AS `LastName`
FROM 
    _UserInfo
    INNER JOIN Cities ON _UserInfo.CityID = Cities.CityID
```

I'd like to `SUM` the total `Cost` of each user's orders from `_UserOrders` and include it in my `SELECT` statement so that I can display `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `TotalOrderCost` for each user.

If the tables had a one-to-one relationship this would be a simple `INNER JOIN`.

```
INNER JOIN _UserOrders ON _UserInfo.UserID = _UserOrders.UserID
```

However, obviously each user can have more than one order, and I am looking for the total.

I could do this with a subquery and a JOIN, but I'm not sure if this is very, very inefficient?

```
SELECT 
    _UserInfo.FirstName AS `FirstName`,
    _UserInfo.SecondName AS `LastName`,
    sq.TotalOrderCost AS `TotalOrderCost`
FROM 
    _UserInfo
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            UserID,
            SUM(Cost) AS `TotalOrderCost`
        FROM 
            _UserOrders
        GROUP BY
            UserId
    ) sq
    ON _UserInfo.UserID = sq.UserID
```

Is there a more efficient way to do things? Is this a poor workaround?

(I was wondering if there is a way to do it as part of the `SELECT` statement, maybe?)

Comment: provide Fiddle of your table along the sample data and result you want, this will help us to work on and find solution.